# Dataproc Spark Streaming Kafka checkpointing warning on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I've got a lot of warning when using Dataproc 1.1 (Spark 2.0.2) with Kafka checkpointing on Google Cloud Storage. I've got the following warn :

```
16/12/11 01:36:02 WARN HttpTransport: exception thrown while executing request
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.listStorageObjectsAndPrefixes(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1069)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.listObjectNames(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1173)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.ForwardingGoogleCloudStorage.listObjectNames(ForwardingGoogleCloudStorage.java:182)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.listObjectNames(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:381)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getInferredItemInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1286)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getInferredItemInfos(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1311)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfos(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1212)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.rename(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:640)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.rename(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1091)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.CheckpointWriter$CheckpointWriteHandler.run(Checkpoint.scala:241)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This goes on several times and eventually just block our spark streaming job on a task that goes on. I've got other warning too before :

```
16/12/10 18:05:23 WARN ReceivedBlockTracker: Exception thrown while writing record: BatchCleanupEvent(ArrayBuffer()) to the WriteAheadLog.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.BatchedWriteAheadLog.write(BatchedWriteAheadLog.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.writeToLog(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.cleanupOldBatches(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.cleanupOldBlocksAndBatches(ReceiverTracker.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.clearCheckpointData(JobGenerator.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:190)
... 9 more
16/12/10 18:05:23 WARN ReceivedBlockTracker: Failed to acknowledge batch clean up in the Write Ahead Log.
```

Does anyone have the same issues ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar errors in checkpointing to google storage recently. I started checkpointing to hdfs in dataproc rather than google storage as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Indeed, that's what we are doing too. But by doing so, we do not benefit from Google Cloud Storage data checkpointing across Dataproc clusters. I'm thinking about updating or moving jobs around cluster for example. I'll try to contact the support as soon as I can. I've just post it here in case someone got a solution to work with Google Cloud Storage directy.

Comment: Try switching your bucket to regional. We had better performance  using regional buckets than multi-regional.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We were already in a regional bucket for this. I tried to contact the google support. They said it's something in the client with Google Cloud Storage but I'm just using the client provided in the dataproc cluster with no additional setup than pointing to a gs bucket.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: I use regional bucketing and switched back and not facing this issue frequently.